# Power query to split every nth row of column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a column of this format:

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| 01/01/01 |
| £20 |
| String |
| 02/01/01 |
| £30 |
| String 2 |

I want to split the column every 3 rows. E.g. to produce the following table.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/01 | £20 | String 1 |
| 02/01/01 | £30 | String 2 |

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. It's usually a just a matter of adding an index column; then an integer/division column with a divisor of 3, and grouping on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming table1 starts at Sheet1!A1, and table2 starts at Sheet2!A1. Just put this in Sheet2!A1 and drag to Sheet2!C2 :

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*3+COLUMN()-1,0)
```

Idea : use row & column numbers to 'drive' the row offset. That should do. ( :

Answer (score 2):

You need some transformation in your data. Incorporate this below **Advanced Query Editor** code for your table-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjDUByOlWJ1opUOLjQzAjOCSosy8dDDTwAhFgTGyAgUjbEpMUJQYK8XGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Column 1" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column 1", type text}}),

    //-- NEW STEPS STARTED FROM HERE

    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Number.RoundDown(([Index]-1)/3)+1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Number.Mod([Index],3)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom.1", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom.1", type text}}, "en-US")[Custom.1]), "Custom.1", "Column 1"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"1", "Date"}, {"2", "Price"}, {"0", "Details"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: For someone that has no idea how to use Power Query, how would you use this, and what information is relevant to change in the code to make it work with our own data?

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence This is really difficult to explain here :(

Comment: What was the logic behind using 'each Number.RoundDown(([Index]-1)/3)+1' for the #'AddedColumn' variable?

Answer (score 1):

Enter this formula in the cell of a blank column in the same row on which your data start (can be on another sheet). Then adjust the formula as described below and copy it 2 extra columns to the right and all the way down as far as your list goes.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,3)=0,OFFSET($A2,COLUMN()-3,0),"")
```

Required adjustments:-

1. `$A2` specify the column of your data. Make sure the column is marked absolute (**$**A). It can be on another sheet but it must be in the same sheet row as the formula.
2. Test `=ROW()-2`. The result must be 0. If you paste to another row adjust the minus (-0 to -2) so that the result equals zero. Use that number. If you end up with -0 omit the calculation.
3. In `COLUMN()-3` the "3" is the number of the column in which you paste the formula. I had it in column C which is column #3. If you have it in column A it would be `COLUMN()-1`

After copying across and down your list is ready but it has a lot of blank rows.

1. Copy the entire range and *Paste > Paste Special> Values*. That will replace the formulas with data.
2. Now Filter out the blanks and copy the ready table to the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty way of doing this for anyone who struggled with the other better choices.

I just used remove rows in the reduce rows area to remove alternating rows. I just made 3 different Queries, and had each query start deleting every 2 rows starting from a different point. everything lines up at the end.
[Picture of removal settings to only leave the 3rd row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMFzp.png)

its really not graceful but it worked really well for me.